# PDF to movie converter

Tags: gratis, pdf, media-converter, file-converter

I look for a software to convert a PDF file to a movie file (for example MP4).

The basic requirements are:

- Free
- Slide show or animation support to ease viewing the PDF contents on the screen

Nice to have requirements:

- Text to speech (read the PDF to audio and encode it with the movie)
- Highlighting the words as read them in the output video

Comment: You want some sort of autoscroll?

Comment: I'm not clear why you wouldn't just use a screen recorder for this.

Answer (score 1):

You may check this github project:

https://github.com/puraminy/pdf2mp4

That's a linux bash file to convert a pdf file to a video in mp4 format. It scans the pages of the pdf file using a sliding window and save them as frames in a folder, then it creates a video from the frames.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket yeah the website was gone. I updated my answer to give another source

Comment: I just noticed your new answer is for Linux, and your question is for Windows.  Would  you mind editing one or the other?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket thank you for suggestion. I edited the question.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I removed the Windows tag, as it no longer applies.

Answer (score -1):

> You can use
>   [A-PDF](http://www.a-pdf.com/faq/how-can-i-convert-pdf-to-video-file-mpeg-avi-wmv.htm)
>   to Video to make video format slideshow from PDF files. And you can
>   output the video in optional formats (MPEG, AVI or WMV) with custom
>   settings. See how to publish video file from PDF.
>
> 1. Download and start A-PDF to Video, add PDF file (3 slides only for trial version);
> 2. Customize the PDF slides with various settings such as proportions, background and effects;
> 3. You can preview the video before publishing;
> 4. Click "Build to video" button and choose format to output video: MPEG, AVI or WMV.

Comment: Please try to use your own words in answers instead of copying from external sources. Also, use a list of features similar to the OP criteria. Example: Non-free, Runs on Windows, etc... Check [this post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/356/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality) for more information

Comment: Its not free and 3 slides in trial version is too low

Comment: Also remember to show how your recommended software matches the requirements named; this part is completely missing in your answer.